# How to add a seam to my cloth bag? Can't get edge loop to shrink in the right way

Tags: modeling

I've been trying to make a storage bag but every time I try I just can't seem to get it right. I've followed this tutorial [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112052/how-to-easily-add-cloth-seam-channel-to-a-model)

But it doesn't seem to be working correctly for me, I may not be understanding it fully. Here is what I want to create: [image]

Here is the result I get when I follow the steps in the tutorial: 
[image]

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated, or maybe there's a simpler way? 
Thanks 
EDIT: Was about to upload the original blender file but it crashed and my work was lost

Comment: did you check this tutorial? https://youtu.be/Ebx2qbBlvh0?t=555

Comment: Awesome! Whatever I was searching wasn't flagging this one up, thanks man